# Is it possible to use contexts and buffered channels as queue? And I'm not sure if this is thread safe or not

Tags: go, thread-safety, go-context

I need to create a queue that passes data to multiple consumers.
Can I make it using buffered channel and context?
And I'm not sure if this is thread safe or not

Here's the sample code I'm talking about:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    runQueue()
}

func runQueue() {
    // When the buffer is full
    // sending channel is blocked
    queue := make(chan string, 10000)

    // If there are too few consumer,
    // the channel buffer will be full, and the sending channel will be blocked.
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()
    consumerCount := 5
    go runProducer(queue, ctx, cancel)
    for i := 0; i < consumerCount; i++ {
        go runConsumer(queue, ctx)
    }
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        // close channel to let goroutine get ctx.Done()
        close(queue)
    }
}

func runConsumer(queue chan string, ctx context.Context) {
    for {
        data := <-queue
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        default:

        }
        fmt.Println(data)
        <-time.After(time.Millisecond * 1000)
    }
}

func runProducer(queue chan string, ctx context.Context, cancel context.CancelFunc) {
    for {
        fmt.Println("get data from server")
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        default:

        }
        // dataList will be filled from other server
        dataList, err := getSomethingFromServer()
        if err != nil {
            if err.Error() == "very fatal error" {
                cancel()
                return
            }
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        default:

        }
        for _, el := range dataList {
            queue <- el
        }
        <-time.After(time.Millisecond * 2000)
    }
}

func getSomethingFromServer() ([]string, error) {
    var newList []string
    for i := 1; i < 4; i++ {
        newList = append(newList, strconv.Itoa(i))
    }
    return newList, nil
}
```

Is it thread safe?
And Is my logic going well?

If there are any mistakes, I would like to receive feedback

Please let me know if there is a better practice.

Answer (score 2):

1. Contexts are thread-safe. https://go.dev/blog/context

> A Context is safe for simultaneous use by multiple goroutines. Code can pass a single Context to any number of goroutines and cancel that Context to signal all of them.

So in go realms safe by multiple goroutines ~ thread-safe, since you never know on which threads (same/different) goroutines are running

2. Channels are thread-safe - https://go.dev/ref/spec#Channel_types

> A single channel may be used in send statements, receive operations, and calls to the built-in functions cap and len by any number of goroutines without further synchronization

Channels use a mutex under-the-hood
https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/chan.go#L51

3. For concurrency patterns take a look at really good go blog posts:

- https://go.dev/blog/pipelines
- https://go.dev/blog/io2013-talk-concurrency

Comment: Thank you for answer.

But I'm not sure my logic is going well, and goroutines always exits..

Is there any goroutine not finished because blocked by the receiving channel?